# How to set HTML header using Mustache

Tags: java, html, jersey, mustache

I'm using [Mustache.java](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java) and I did not find a simple way to set the HTML header. I want to set `content="text/html` for example.

My Java code for rendering a mustache file is:

```
@Path("/home")
@GET
public static String getIndexPage(){
        MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
        Mustache mustache = mf.compile(MustacheFileName);
        StringWriter b = new StringWriter();
        try {
            mustache.execute(b, new MustacheObject()).flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b.toString();
}
```

**Notes:**

- I'm running my application using [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/)
- The return HTML content is `text/plain` (checked that using dev tools in chrome browser)
- My current solution is to set in `MustacheFileName`:

  `<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  ...
  </head>`

So, is there an elegant way to do it instead of setting that manually in the HTML template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an elegant solution for this:

Define the `GET` method to produce `MediaType.TEXT_HTML`:

```
@Path("/home")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public static String getIndexPage(){
        MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
        Mustache mustache = mf.compile(MustacheFileName);
        StringWriter b = new StringWriter();
        try {
            mustache.execute(b, new MustacheObject()).flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems rather unrelated to mustache. Nevertheless, using normal jersey REST application mechanics, you'd switch to returning a Response object instead of a simple string, along the lines of:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/home")
@GET
public static Response getIndexPage(){
    MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
    Mustache mustache = mf.compile(MustacheFileName);
    StringWriter b = new StringWriter();
    try {
        mustache.execute(b, new MustacheObject()).flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Response.ok()
       .entity(b.toString())
       .header("whatever-header-you-need", "... its value")
       .build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! 
You might want to take a look at my answer, I'v just came up with another elegant solution.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I did not pay attention to the concrete header you needed. For your case, @Produces is the best way to go. Keep the answer above in your book for general cases, where you do not have direct annotation support.